# Why take different avatar each time?

Tags: vishnu, avatars

Each time Lord take avatar it is in different form.
Why not take avatar of same animal or same human each time? Is there any significance of incarnating as different form?

Comment: It depends on the situation. In many cases, The demons ask for death and Brahma refuses. Later they ask  weird boons that they must be killed by only "X" and under some circumstances. To fulfill those criteria, Vishnu takes the incarnations and does the deed.

Comment: A normal human being plays different roles - as a wife or husband, mother or father, as worker in office, judge in a courtroom, take out criminals as a policeman etc. Based on the need, the same person can switch roles at a moments notice. Same with God. He can be born as a brāhmaṇa, a kṣatriya or even an animal.

Comment: @sv Then what would be the difference between human and God?

Comment: Not sure I follow your question. Human is a normal soul (ātmā), God is supreme soul (paramātmā). My example was to answer your title question (Why take different avatar each time?) just as a human can take different roles in a given life, God can too, based on need.

Comment: ***Incarnation of lords is mandate when there is lack of Dharma and love towards fellowman.... Incarnation is the way lord uses to come to the places (Different Yuga) where sins are common as practice as he can not come to our place as himself...***

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is given in Shreemad Bhagvat Purana in Skanda 1
Chapter 3 , (The description of Avataras) this  chapter is about twenty two avataras of Lord Vishnu. This chapter tells us why lord has took many forms in different avatara with explanation.

Form the description given in this chapter we come to conclusion that , lord took many **forms like (Animal ,Siddha ,Yagna ,king , medicine god ,female ,amimal plus human etc.)**  in different avataras according to **situation , need and purpose.**

So in each  avatara lord performed various different tasks that were suitable to that form he took.eg. it was necessary to take Narashimha avatara in half human half lion form , because of boon Hiranyakashipu received or it was necessary to take human form as Veda Vyasa to compile vedas , which **simply were not suitable** to perform other than human forms.Like Wise It was  suitable to take tortoise form to to support Mandarachal mountain ,during churning of ocean.

Following shlokas mentions some of the forms and the purpose of lord to take that form -:

> तत: सप्तम आकुत्यां **रुचेर्यज्ञोsभ्य** जायत।
>  स यामाद्ये:
>   सुरगणैरपात्स्वायम्भुवान्तरम्॥१२॥
>
> tataḥ saptama ākūtyāṁ rucer yajño ’bhyajāyata sa yāmādyaiḥ sura-gaṇair
>   apāt svāyambhuvāntaram
>
> Meaning-: The seventh **incarnation was Yajña**, the son of Prajāpati
>   Ruci and his wife Ākūti. He controlled the period during the change of
>   the Svāyambhuva Manu and was assisted by demigods such as His son
>   Yāma.[**SB 1.3.12**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/3/12)
>
> ---
>
> ऋषिभिर्याचितो भेजे नवमं **पार्थिवं
>   वपु:**।
>  दुग्धेमामोषधीर्विप्रास्तेनायं स उशत्तम: ॥१४॥
>
> ṛṣibhir yācito bheje navamaṁ pārthivaṁ vapuḥ
>  dugdhemām oṣadhīr
>   viprās tenāyaṁ sa uśattamaḥ
>
> **Meaning** -: O brāhmaṇas, in the ninth incarnation, the Lord, prayed for by sages, accepted the body of a **king** [Pṛthu] who
>   **cultivated** the land to yield various produce, and for that reason the earth was beautiful and attractive.[**SB** **1.3.14**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/3/14)
>
> ---
>
> सुरासुराणामुदधिं मन्थतां मंदराचलं।
>  दध्रे **कमठरूपेण** पृष्ठ एकादशे
>   विभु:॥१६॥
>
> surāsurāṇām udadhiṁ mathnatāṁ mandarācalam
>  dadhre kamaṭha-rūpeṇa
>   pṛṣṭha ekādaśe vibhuḥ
>
> **Meaning** - The eleventh incarnation of the Lord took the form of a **tortoise** whose shell served as a **pivot** for the **Mandarācala** Hill, which was being used as a churning rod by the theists and
>   atheists of the universe.[**SB 1.3.16**](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/3/16)
>
> ---
>
> तत: सप्तदशे जात:
>   सत्यवत्यां पराशरात।
>  चक्रे वेदतरो: शाखा दृष्ट्वा
>   पुंसोsल्पमेधस:॥२१॥
>
> tataḥ saptadaśe jātaḥ satyavatyāṁ parāśarāt
>  cakre veda-taroḥ śākhā
>   dṛṣṭvā puṁso ’lpa-medhasaḥp
>
> **Meaning** - Thereafter, in the seventeenth incarnation of Godhead, **Śrī Vyāsadeva** appeared in the womb of Satyavatī through Parāśara Muni, and he divided the one Veda into several branches and
>   subbranches, seeing that the people in general were less intelligent.
>
> [**SB 1.3.21**](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/3/21)

---

You can read whole chapter [**Here**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/3)