# Why should i read any Purana which is not Sattva, like the Bhavishya Parva/Purana?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, bhagavata-purana, vishnu-purana, ignorance

It is said that sattva is the highest mode so why should one read a purana of a lower mode?

Am I confusing things?

Comment: It's for the people who live a life of that mode it is for them to perform some good karmas by worshipping Shriman Narayana in the form of Different gods, and it surely will improve them to a good position to attain moksha in this or the other life by realizing the sattva mode so it acts as a cushion(y)  landing for a falling person, better than an impulsive jerk.

Comment: Yes, there is no need to read those other Puranas which are not sattvic. The best thing is to read the sattvic ones only, such as Srimad Bhagavatam (Bhagavata Purana), Vishnu Purana, etc. Not only that but it can even be harmful and dangerous to read those Puranas which are under the influence of lower qualities of rajas (passion) and tamas (darkness, ignorance) because those Puranas often contain some false teachings which can pollute the consciousness of a man who is reading them and believes them to be true. So the best thing is to avoid such low quality texts.

Comment: this distinction is spurious and a possible "vaishnava" construct.

Comment: The division of the Puranas into the sattvic ones and the tamasic ones is not spurious but is genuine, and everyone can see it easily if he knows Vedanta and teaching of the Sruti (Upanishads, etc). Not long ago we have seen one such example of the verses from one Purana called Devi Bhagavata that teaches tamasic verses and doctrines, see how I explained it at https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18691/why-does-narayana-take-incarnation-if-he-says-i-dislike-taking-avataara#comment51480_18691 Those verses are contrary to the teaching of Vedanta, Sruti and sattvic Puranas.